# How can I avoid port collision?

Tags: networking, server, haproxy

everyone! I was recently assigned to a task.

There is a Client is running on linux servers for system and security monitoring. It's configuration can cause a port collision with our haproxy running on certain port due to implemented randomized port listening (security feature).

If this port is keep by accident by a client, haproxy is unable to start. Haproxy systemctl output does report a port in use exception. Issue can be resolved by rebooting server (or restarting the client by Linux admins).

My manager suggests that switching haproxy configuration to another port? What would you do in this position? And could I make changes in haproxy configration? Because I don't have much deeper knowladge about it.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu? If it foes what version is it?

Comment: Maybe ask on server fault?

Comment: Can the monitor application be configured to use/not-use certain ports or port ranges? Or can you start haproxy before the monitoring application (systemd startup dependencies)?